# Condition in ternary operator is being ignored within a 'Where' method. Is there another better approach to query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-method-syntax

I'm trying to implement a method to retrieve data from database with EF and Linq method syntax. The method has 5 parameters (four List and one string), each parameter must work as a filter for the query result.

Using a ternary operator within "Where" methods work in some expressions (1-4) of the follwing code, but in expression (5) the Where condition is totally ignored, no matter the string value of "nameFilter", using the ternary operator in expression (5) is ignored, while debugging I have checked that the condition result in `!nameFilter.Equals("")` was true when nameFilter value is "".

```
public IEnumerable<UNIDADE> RecuperarPorEmpresaEstadoCITYTipoUnidadeFiltroNAME( List<int> companiesId, List<int> statesId, List<int> citiesId, List<int> typesId, string nameFilter ) 
{
    return base.Dataset
            .Where( u => companiesId.Count() > 0 ? companiesId.Contains( u.COMPANY_ID ) : true ) //1
            .Where( u => statesId.Count() > 0 ?  statesId.Contains( u.CITY.STATE_ID ) : true ) //2
            .Where( u => citiesId.Count() > 0 ?  citiesId.Contains( u.CITY_ID ) : true ) //3
            .Where( u => typesId.Count() > 0 ? typesId.Contains( u.TYPE_ID ) : true ) //4
            .Where( u => !nameFilter.Equals("") ? u.NAME.ToUpper().Contains( nameFilter.ToUpper() ) : true ); //5
}
```

Finnaly, Trying solve the issue I have changed the expression `.Where( u => !nameFilter.Equals("") ? u.NAME.ToUpper().Contains( nameFilter.ToUpper() ) : true );`

to

`.Where( u => nameFilter.Length > 0 ? u.NAME.ToUpper().Contains( nameFilter.ToUpper() ) : true )`

And it worked.

I'm new to C# and Entity Framework, so I'd like to understand why comparing to a string the ternary operator was somehow being ignored while comparing with 'Length' gave me the expected result. Is there another approach to run this query with Entity Framework?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the difference between `filtroNomeUnidade` and `nameFilter`?

Comment: It seems strange that you're using a ternary operator with hard-coded `true` values instead of an `OR`... i.e. `.Where(u => string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameFilter) || u.NAME.ToUpper().Contains(nameFilter.ToUpper())` (although this does not answer your question). It appears that what "works" is using some completely different collection and property (i.e. `filtroNomeUnidade` and `NOME`)

Comment: @RufusL Sorry, I actually had to translate all the variables names to make more sense here in SO but I forgot to translate that one. I have already fixed it.

Comment: @RufusL I've changed the code as you suggested using `.Where(u => string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameFilter) || u.NAME.ToUpper().Contains(nameFilter.ToUpper()` and it worked, but if the code is implemented like this isn't possible to occur a NullReferenceException once the `nameFilter` is `null`?

Comment: Nope....in your original code that is possible because you're attempting to access the `Equals` method of `nameFilter`, but in mine we are checking for `null` first (using the static `IsNullOrEmpty` method of the `string` class). If that returns true, then the second part of the `||` condition is ignored.

Comment: @RufusL I'll accept your suggestion (`.Where(u => string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameFilter) || u.NAME.ToUpper().Contains(nameFilter.ToUpper())`) as answer because it made the code work and more legible. Thank you!